# Who is the Rig Vedic god Manyu who resembles Indra?

Tags: shiva, rig-veda, indra, vedic-gods, shatapatha-brahmana

**[Rig Veda Book 10 Verse 83](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10083.htm)** mentions someone called Manyu while describing the exploits of Indra:

> 1. HE who hath reverenced thee, **Manyu, destructive bolt,** breeds for himself forthwith all conquering energy. Ārya and Dāsa will we conquer with thine aid, with thee the Conqueror, with conquest conquest-sped.
> 2. **Manyu was Indra, yea, the God, was Manyu, Manyu was Hotar, Varuṇa, Jātavedas.** The tribes of human lineage worship Manyu. Accordant with thy fervour, Manyu, guard us.
> 3. Come hither, Manyu, mightier tham the mighty; chase, with thy fervour for ally, our foemen. **Slayer of foes, of Vṛtra,** and of Dasyu, bring thou to us all kinds of wealth and treasure.
> 4. For thou art, Manyu, of surpassing vigour, fierce, queller of the foe, and self-existent, Shared by all men, victorious, subduer: vouchsafe to us superior strengith in battles.
> 5. I have departed, still without a portion, wise God! according to thy will, the Mighty.I, feeble man, was wroth thee, O Manyu I am myself; come thou to give me vigour.
> 6. Come hither. I am all thine own; advancing turn thou to me, Victorious, All-supporter! **Come to me, Manyu, Wielder of the Thunder:** bethink thee of thy friend, and slay the Dasyus.
> 7. Approach, and on my right hand hold thy station: so shall we slay a multitude of foemen. The best of meath I offer to support thee: may we be first to drink thereof in quiet.

Now [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manyu_(deity)) mentions that the Shatpatha Brahman equates him with Rudra but by the above verses about him wielding the Vajra & slaying Vritra, it seems he is more related to Indra. **Are there any more details available about him in any other scripture?**

Comment: it seems that the mentioned topic does not belong to  RV 10.82 so please correct the reference.

Comment: Shatapata brahmana mentions manyu either a form or name of Lord rudra and in rig veda even agni dev and saraswati devi has called to kill vritra.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda yes many other deities are also associated with the same feat that's why I want to find if there are any other scriptures that help solve the confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wiki is right. Manyu is one of the Rudra among many forms of Rudra. As described in [this chapter](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe43/sbe4330.htm) of Shatapatha Brahamana:

> 6. And as to why he performs the Satarudriya offering. When Pragâpati had become disjointed, the deities departed from him. **Only one god did not leave him, to wit, Manyu extended he remained within. He (Pragâpati) cried, and the tears of him that fell down settled on Manyu. He became the hundred-headed, thousand-eyed, hundred-quivered Rudra.** And the other drops that fell down, spread over these worlds in countless numbers, by thousands; and inasmuch as they originated from crying (rud), they were called Rudras (roarers). That hundred-headed, thousand-eyed, hundred-quivered Rudra, with his bow strung, and his arrow fitted to the string, was inspiring fear, being in quest of food. The gods were afraid of him.
>      
>      They spake unto Pragâpati 'We are afraid of this one, lest he should hurt us!' He spake, 'Gather food for him, and appease him therewith!' **They gathered for him that food, the Satarudriya** (offering), and thereby appeased him; and inasmuch as they thereby appeased (sam) the hundred-headed (satasîrsha) Rudra, it is called Satasîrsharudrasamanîya,--and satasîrsharudrasamanîya, doubtless, is what they mystically call Satarudriya, for the gods love the mystic. And in like manner does this (Sacrificer) **now gather for him that food, the Satarudriya, and appease him thereby.**

The passage above itself clears Manyu is one of the forms of Rudra. Regarding other things like holding Vajra, RigVeda too calls Lord Rudra as 'Holder of Vajra' in 2.33.3 and also in AtharvaVeda 4.28.6. Similarly, AtharvaVeda 4.28.3 also states Lord Bhava-Sarva as destroyer of Vritta:

> “sahasrākṣáu vr̥trahánā huveháṃ dūrégavyūtī stuvánn my ugráu |
>   yā́v asyéśathe dvipádo yáu cátuṣpadas táu no muñcatam áṃhasaḥ ||” (Atharvaveda 4:28:03)
>   
>   “**The thousand-eyed slayers of Vritra** both do I invoke. I go praising the two strong gods (ugrau) whose pastures extend far. Ye who rule all these two-footed and four-footed creatures [Pasupati], deliver us from grief and trouble”.

And Srimad Bhagvatam also [mentions](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/12/chapter-view) Manyu as among the 11 Rudras:

> **मन्युर्** मनुर् महिनसो
>    महाञ् छिव ऋतध्वजः
>   उग्ररेता भवः कालो
>    वामदेवो धृतव्रतः
>   
>   Lord Brahmā said: My dear boy Rudra, you have eleven other names: **Manyu,** Manu, Mahinasa, Mahān, Śiva, Ṛtadhvaja, Ugraretā, Bhava, Kāla, Vāmadeva and Dhṛtavrata.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why the Vedic seers had to make certain things so difficult to decipher. I understand the concept of henotheism but why mention five different people doing the same very specific thing like killing Vritra!

Comment: Dr. Vineet Aggarwal the vedic seers are not trying to make it hard. They were not focusing on the petty quarrel between Puranic Sects arguing who is the bigger/powerful superhero.  They composed each hymn to represent a CONCEPT of Rta. They were not trying to compete with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Manyu in Manyu Suktam of Rigveda god of terror and it is Lord Narasimha. In Manyu Suktam, Lord Narasimha who is called as Manyu is described as the controlling power behind Indra who killed Vritrasura, Agni, Varuna and all gods. Sripad Madhvacharya explained about this in bhashyas. Many Vaishnava saints wrote commentaries on Manyu Suktam. Dhirendra Tirtha, a Vaishnava Saints, describes Narasimha as the internal controller of Rudra and who is the embodiment of knowledge. Sripad Madhvacharya in his "Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya" said When Bhima killed Dushasana in Mahabharata war, in order to terrorize the enemies Bhima had tasted blood applied blood to his face again and again intensely, remembering the divine lord Narasimha and recited the Manyu Sukta hymn with devotion. Among Vaishnavas Manyu Suktam is always recited during the time abhisheka to Lord Narasimha.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this answer . I have upvoted. Please try to add sources like Shri Madhwacharya's bhashya or any other Acharyas work amd quote the source.